# Sharepoint 2013 Crawl error when crawling Tif Files

Tags: sharepoint-server

When crawling Tif file in SharePoint 2013 i get the error 'Processing this item failed because of a timeout when parsing its contents' when reviewing the logs it has the Error ID 2147810853. I cannot find any reference to this Error ID.
The files are smaller than the MaxDownloadSize property. I have increased the timeout value to 600 seconds in the search service application, and I am not running out of memory. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](https://albandrodsmemory.com/2015/06/04/enabling-tiff-images-for-sharepoint-2013-search/#:~:text=SharePoint%202013%20Search%20has%20the,changed%20since%20the%202010%20version)

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.When you get this error first make sure you have enough resources (Ram,CPU, and Storage) on all farm servers participating in the crawl.

2.Make sure this settings are set to the default settings :

Go to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Search\Runtime\1.0\noderunner.exe.config** and make sure

3.Run the following PowerShell to change this settings :

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel Reduced
Restart-Service SPSearchHostController
```

Confirm that the Performance Level configuration has changed by running the following command

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchService
```

4.Increase the timeout value under "**Farm Search Management**" from 60 to 600

There is the same post in the Q&A Forum：

[Sharepoint 2013 Crawl error when crawling Tif Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/383803/sharepoint-2013-crawl-error-when-crawling-tif-file.html?childToView=384560#answer-384560)

Answer (score 0):

The settings were already correct. It was a combination of issues. I had moved all the crawl components to another server but had not set up a timer job to restart the Search Service every morning (something we have found improves the Crawl Performances). The real problem was the File Format for TIF. I removed the File Type within Search then Remove--SPEnterpriseSearchFileFormat for tif. Restarted the Search Service then added these back in. one Full Crawl laeter and everything was working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm sharing. Have a nice day!